# Return 404 in Apache if directory index file is requested directly

Tags: apache-2.2

My index files are the standard `index.html`. While `GET /dir/` returns /dir/index.html, I would like to return a 404 status code to the request `GET /dir/index.html`. Is there a simple way to do this under Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/dir/(index.html)?$ /404 [L]
```